# Windows LAN certificate possible to add to debian for wired network access

Tags: networking, debian, lan, certificate

A company uses a certificate (CER file) on their Windows PCs to access the wired network. Is it possible to add this to a laptop with debian, so the wired connection can be used too?

In Windows it has to be added to root certificate store and activated in the network settings in tab authentification.

Is there something like this in debian? I only found how to add it to a wireless connection, but that is not the wired connection. Debian is stretch with Mate desktop.

Comment: Your comment is unclear to me - What does the certificate enable?  Is it a client side certificate that is presented to the remove website to verify you, a root certificate to facilitate a corporate firewall/proxy or something else?  Advising  how you add this to the wireless connection may provide sufficient information to help advise how to add it to a wired connection.

Comment: It appears to be a root certificate to access the corporate wired lan, or firewall. I simply added it in Windows in MMC, then went to LAN settings-authentication and enabled this specific certificate, which was added to this list after adding it in MMC. I hope it is more clear?

Comment: My guess this is about 802.1x authentication. I am 99% sure this is supported on Linux.